# Year change not give result in mysql server

Tags: mysql, sql, date, select

In this question, I have 2 query

```
1) SELECT * FROM order WHERE order-date BETWEEN '12/01/2013' AND '12/31/2013'
```

This query give proper data from the table.

But in 2 query

```
2) SELECT * FROM order WHERE order-date BETWEEN '12/01/2013' AND '01/10/2014'
```

This query not display any date from table, how this not display any data, there is some year change problem in  mysql server.

Please help me.

Comment: Don't use `BETWEEN` [to compare date/time/timestamps](https://sqlblog.org/2011/10/19/what-do-between-and-the-devil-have-in-common) (given that you can specify timestamp precision in MySQL, this still applies).  What is the type/format of `order-date`?

Answer (score 1):

You have to convert string to date for comparing two dates otherwise it consider as string. For that you have to use [**STR_TO_DATE()**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date) function

Try this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM `order` o
WHERE STR_TO_DATE(o.orderDate, '%m/%d/%Y') BETWEEN '2013-12-01' AND '2013-12-31'

SELECT * 
FROM `order` o
WHERE STR_TO_DATE(o.orderDate, '%m/%d/%Y') BETWEEN '2013-12-01' AND '2014-01-10'
```

Comment: @user3180456 You're most welcome... Take a tour to stackoverflow on http://stackoverflow.com/tour